# Type error trying ng build --prod with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

again.
Maybe I'm having a silly mistake, but I'm starting my firsts steps with Angular 4 and my knowledge is of novice.

I'm trying to `build` the production version for publish my website but Angular CLI returns the current error:

> Error in login.component.html: Property 'password' does not exist on type 'LoginComponent'.

**login.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <form #loginForm="ngForm" class="loginForm">
      <h3 class="text-center">Administrador</h3>
      <hr>
      <div class="alert alert-info" *ngIf="status.loading"> {{ status.loading }} </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="status.error"> {{ status.error }} </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="status.success"> {{ status.success }} </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tfEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ngModel id="tfEmail" #email="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tfPassword">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" ngModel id="tfPassword" #email="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="login(email, password)">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { ConfirmComponent } from '../../modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css', '../admin.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  email: string;
  password: string;

  status = {
    loading: '',
    success: '',
    error: ''
  };

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }

  login(email, password) {
    this.status.loading = 'Procesando datos...';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.status = { loading: '', success: '', error: '' };
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(_ => {
        this.status.success = 'Login correcto. Redirigiendo...';
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.href = '/';
        }, 3000);
      }).catch(error => {
        this.status.error = 'Ocurrió un error. Revise sus datos.';
        console.error(error);
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Input() decorator

http://learnangular2.com/inputs/

Comment: I thank you @jetblack not only for your response, but also for the link you posted, will be very usefull for me.